# Branch Deep Linking not working in Google Analytics hitCallback

Tags: google-analytics, branch.io

I'm using both Google Analytics and branch.io in this [website](http://xiaobandeng.palmdrive.cn/app/discovery).

The website is designed for mobile.

The problem is that when clicking the banner with text "OPEN", the app cannot be opened.

Here is the code for the click:

```
$scope.openApp = () => {
  let appOpened = false;
  const open = () => {
    if (!appOpened) {
      appOpened = true;
      branch.deepviewCta();
    }
  };

  $timeout(open, 1000);

  ga('send', 'event', 'homepage', 'download', {
    hitCallback() {
      open();
    }
  });
};
```

If I get rid of the GA code, it works fine:

```
$scope.openApp = () => {
  let appOpened = false;
  const open = () => {
    if (!appOpened) {
      appOpened = true;
      branch.deepviewCta();
    }
  };

  $timeout(open, 1000);

  open();

};
```

The reason I put `open()` in `hitCallback` is to make sure GA sends out the hit because `open()` will redirect to another page.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Alex from Branch.io here:

The Branch `deepviewCta()` function works on iOS 9+ by triggering an automatic redirect to a Universal Link URL (which opens the app) and then going to a fallback URL if that fails. But Apple is very specific about the situations in which a Universal Link is allowed to launch the app (including things like how long of a pause is allowed before redirection). Of course these restrictions are not public, so all we can do is guess. My suspicion is that putting the `deepviewCta()` function inside a GA callback is falling outside of Apple’s rules, so the app never opens and you are instead being sent to the fallback URL.

I can think of two options here:

1. You can build some way to trigger the GA and Branch functions separately so that they don’t conflict with Apple’s requirements.
2. We actually have a brand new, one-click integration with Google Analytics, which you can read about [here](https://branch.io/data-integrations/) and [here](https://dev.branch.io/third-party-integrations/google-analytics/). If you set that up, you’ll get all Branch-related events automatically instead of needing to manually collect link click data.

Hopefully that helps!